# VERY simple Javascript templating

Tags: javascript, templates

Could somebody inform me of a library that offers basic HTML templating?

I.e. all I need is a library that translates a placeholder into the literal value in HTML. I.e., say I have the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>My Label:</label>

        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input placeholder="Enter name..." />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I would like, is to mark up some placeholders in my markup which, ideally, in the simplistic view, points to a javascript variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{myApp.labels.title}}</title>

        <script>
            (function () {
                window.myApp = {
                    labels: {
                        title: 'My Title',
                        label1: 'My Label',
                        name1: 'Name',
                        placeholder: 'Enter name'
                    }
                };
            }());
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>{{myApps.labels.label1}}:</label>

        <div>
            <label>{{myApps.labels.name1}}:</label>
            <input placeholder="{{myApps.labels.placeholder}}..." />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have looked at libraries such as Handlebars.js and Mustache.js but these either:

1. Imply the mark up you want is deeply tied in with the model.
2. Use JavaScript to bind a piece of mark up to their respective variables

Thus, is there anything simpler (if what I have wrote makes sense)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply roll your own:

```
function tmpl (markup, tmplvars, prefix) {
    for(var key in tmplvars) {
        if (tmplvars[key] instanceof Object)
            markup = tmpl(markup, tmplvars[key], prefix ? (prefix + "." + key) : key);
        else
            markup = markup.replace(new RegExp("\{\{" + (prefix? (prefix + "." + key) : key) + "\}\}", "gi"), tmplvars[key]);
    }
    return markup;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var MyTemplate = '<label>{{username.label}}<input placeholder="{{username.placeholder}}"/></label>';
var markup = tmpl(MyTemplate, {username:{label: "Username", placeholder: "Enter your username..."}});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84jz73uc/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realise there was a function called tmpl :)

Comment: Yes that may be because there is no such function. Its defined in the snippet above.

Comment: Oh yeah - ha! Not sure how I missed that :) but either way, very useful - thanks.

Comment: Well how about marking it as the answer then? ;)